# Python GUI Tkinter is not including all libraries or modules to use

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

I am using Pycharm version: Pycharm Community Edition 2017.1 on Windows 7 64 bit edition, and my environment variables are set as below:

> PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\vinsow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib;C:\Users\vinsow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\DLLs;C:\Users\vinsow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6;
>
> PATH: C:\Users\vinsow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\vinsow\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Tcl\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;%PATH%
>
> CLASSPATH:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;.

When I open a new python file using pycharm and type in:

```
import tkinter this works
```

Whereas :

[image]

tkinter.[functions popup] would display very few options:

as in image, Looks like I have to update the path variable or either some things to change in my Pycharm IDE. I am a newbie for a tkinter GUI programming.

Answer (score 1):

You have a file named `tkinter.py`, so it's importing that file rather than the tkinter module. rename `tkinter.py` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Childish Mistake.
Your file is named `tkinter.py` which if you know is the same as the Module `tkinter` when you type `import tkinter`.

So What you are doing is;

```
while 3>2:
   os.starfile('/pathtoyourfile')
```

it is an Infinite Loop going on.
When I was learning python and learning to send emails i named my file email.py and because of that my file was failing try to name you files as `adrgdt.py` something **Unique so you dont run into this error again**

I hope this helps.